# De-Serializing StreamCorrupted

Tags: java, exception, serialization

I have a a problem I have been dealing with for quite some time now. When attempting to de-serialize my custom "Sound" objects in a folder I continue to get 3 exceptions. IOException, NullPointerException, and StreamCorruptedException. Please take a look:

Method for reading sounds:

```
public static Sound readSound(String loc){
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(loc);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        fis.close();
        ois.close();

        return (Sound)ois.readObject();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed to read a serialized object.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Exceptions/Errors Received: http://gyazo.com/b53faa9590adf6448bf14db11f275325
(Too much to paste here and it pastes incorrectly)

Loading the sounds:
(add sound just adds the sound to an ArrayList as well as a JComboBox)

```
private static File saveDirFile = new File("/Users/francisj12/Desktop/ACData/");
private static File saveDirFileSounds = new File(saveDirFile.getPath()+"/sounds/");
public static void loadAllSounds(){
    if(!saveDirFile.exists()){
        saveDirFile.mkdir();
    }
    if(!saveDirFileSounds.exists()){
        saveDirFileSounds.mkdir();
    }

    for(int x=0; x<saveDirFileSounds.list().length; x++){
        try{
            File sndFl = new File(saveDirFileSounds.listFiles()[x].getPath());
            Sound newSound = Serialize.readSound(sndFl.getPath());
            addSound(newSound);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Here it what the .ser files look like: (Once I started using transient on variables so I could serialize my custom Sound object which I dont understand transient yet, it started making the .ser look as follows instead of a ton of weird characters its just one line of weird characters now)
¨ÌsrAlarms.SoundË.®ŸÓÓxp

Hope this is all the information you guys will need thanks so much for your help!

Comment: you should not close the inputstream before return (Sound)ois.readObject(); read your object then close the inputstream.

Comment: @xiaowang thanks so much that seems to have done the trick! I should have realized. If you don't mind I do have one more question when and what exactly does .flush() do for the streams? I know it releases memory but thats all I really know about it.